# It is showing "opl run is not responding. Please rerun the configuration". Why is this error displayed in C-PLEX? How to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, php, spring, cplex, opl

It is showing to rerun the configuration when I have increased the size of my optimization problem. And also, when I try reducing the number of datas  it also takes more than 6 minutes to execute. The constraints showing errors are given as subject to

```
{ 
//constraint for discharging

 forall(i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport)
 {ct1:if(c[j]==5 && 0.7<soc[k][j]<0.9)
 {pevdis[j][k]==(0.9-soc[k][j])*100000;
 //125000000<=pl[i][j]-pevdis[j][k]<=147000000;
}
//else

else
{pevdis[j][k]==0;}}



//constraint for charging
forall(i in nbus, j in tavail, k in nport)
{ct4: if(c[j]==2.5 && soc[k][j]<=0.7 )
 {pevch[j][k]==(0.7-soc[k][j])*100000;
// 125000000<=pl[i][j]+pevch[j][k]<=147000000;
}

else
{pevch[j][k]==0;}

}

forall(i in nbus, j in tavail, k in nport,l in nbus)

{ 
ct5: pbat[j]==pg[i][j]-pl[i][j]+pevdis[j][k]-pevch[j][k];}
forall(i in nbus, j in tavail, k in nbus,l in nbus)
{ct8: if(pbat[j]>0)
  { p[i][j]==v[i][j]*(sum(l in tavail)(v[i][j]*(G[i][l]*deltacos[i][l][j]+B[i][l]*deltasin[i][l][j])));
   p[i][j]*100000000+ pg[i][j]-pl[i][j]-pevch[j][k]+pevdis[j][k]+pbat[j]==0;
  }
 else
 ct11: if (pbat[j]<0)
  {p[i][j]==v[i][j]*(sum(l in nbus)(v[i][j]*(G[i][l]*deltacos[i][l][j]+B[i][l]*deltasin[i][l][j])));
 p[i][j]*100000000+ pg[i][j]-pl[i][j]-pevch[j][k]+pevdis[j][k]-pbat[j]==0;
  }
}}
 execute
 {cplex.threads=1;}
```

Comment: Re-read your own question before posting, please. This is illegible and doesn't make any obvious sense either. See also [ask]. Also, if you have an error message please quote it in full in the question, including any relevant stack trace info, not just a partial version in the title. And please format the code to be readable too, with proper indentation. The more effort you put into making your question clear, the more likely you are to get answers. And review your tags too - how is PHP or spring relevant to this code, for example? At the moment, it's pretty meaningless to be honest. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but it only fixes a small amount of what I mentioned. Please don't paraphrase the error message...post the exact message, as I suggested. And you still need to examine your tags, fix the code formatting, and explain the context properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using if I would rely on slicing.

```
int N=1000000000;
range r=1..N;

dvar int x;

subject to
{
 forall(i in r)
  if(i==2) x==i;
    
    
}
```

takes a lot of time whereas

```
int N=1000000000;
range r=1..N;

dvar int x;

subject to
{
 forall(i in r:i==2)
  x==i;
    
    
}
```

is fast

Comment: Sir, unfortunately it is not working