# "Overflow occurred, please use oplrun -profile ".This error message appears in C-PLEX. How to get rid of it?

Tags: runtime-error, constraints, overflow, cplex, opl

After incorporating the power balance constraint, the overflow occurred. I have also tried using opl run.But it is of no use.
minimize 0.7*sum(i in nbus)(sum(j in tavail)sum(k in nport)((pt[i][j]*1000000-pl[i][j]*1000000-pevch[j][k]+pevdis[j][k])+sum(k in nport)(pevdis[j][k]-pevch[j][k])))- 0.15*(sum (j in tavail)(sum (k in nport)(c[j]*pevdis[j][k])))

```
+0.15* (sum (j in tavail)sum (k in nport)(c[j]*pevch[j][k]));


subject to

{ 
//constraint for discharging

 forall(i in nbus,j in tavail,k in nport)
 {ct1:if(c[j]==5 && 0.7<soc[k][j]<0.9)
 {pevdis[j][k]==(0.9-soc[k][j])*100000;

}
//else

else
{pevdis[j][k]==0;
}}

 
//constraint for charging
forall(i in nbus, j in tavail, k in nport)
{ct4: if(c[j]==2.5 && soc[k][j]<=0.7 )
 {pevch[j][k]==(0.7-soc[k][j])*100000;
 
}

else
{pevch[j][k]==0;}

}
```

forall(i in nbus, j in tavail, k in nport,l in nbus)
{//power balance
{ p[j]==v[j][i]*(sum(l in nbus)(v[j][l]*(G[i][l]*deltacos[i][l][j]+B[i][l]*deltasin[i][l][j])));
p[j]*100000000+ pg[i][j]-pl[i][j]-pevch[j][k]+pevdis[j][k]==0;
}

```
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try what I suggested at

[It is showing "opl run is not responding. Please rerun the configuration". Why is this error displayed in C-PLEX? How to fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74825799/it-is-showing-opl-run-is-not-responding-please-rerun-the-configuration-why-i)

Plus since you have many "pevch[j][k]==0; " you may try to use an array that is not indexed by the full Euclidian product but by the indexes that make sense

See Exploiting sparsity in the CPLEX documentation

> Discusses how to exploit the sparsity of large-scale problems, beyond
> the classical transportation problem exposed in the transp1.mod
> sample.

Comment: Sir, where can I find information on sparsity?

Comment: https://higherlogicdownload.s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/IMWUC/f68174e9-e214-4dea-bd9d-f097007cd5ee_file.PDF?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAVRDO7IEREB57R7MT&Expires=1671346795&Signature=ATYbyARKk%2FQPR4tgCZYN6%2B3KRlw%3D

Comment: Actually, I am not able to figure it out. Because of this issue, I divided my optimization programme into four programs. I am not able to do it in asingle programme as it runs for a very long time and shows opl run not responding or overflow occured.

Comment: Have you tried to use command line oplrun ?

Comment: I have tried that but don't know whether it is done in the right way.

Comment: The oplrun executable enables you to run an OPL model or project externally, that is, directly from the command line instead of launching the IDE. You will find it useful as a pre-deployment step to check speed and memory consumption outside of the IDE and to tune your model on large data sets.

Typically:

to check and compare the results of the execution from the IDE and outside it

to overcome possible IDE slowness or overhead caused by IDE-specific settings

Comment: Can  you please explain the steps for enabling oplrun

Comment: You can use command line or from the IDE https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/launch-oplrun-sessions-directly-cplex-optimization-studio-ide

Comment: I did it in the same way.But still it is showing opl-run not responding.Iam using C-PLEX 22.1.

Comment: Provided link doesnot have the access